# Why are solutions $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ of a $p$-adic variety with one of the $x_i$ invertible called primitive solutions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

In Serre's arithmetic he calls a solution $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ of a $p$-adic variety
$$
X = \mathbb{V}(f^{(1)},\ldots,f^{(k)}) \subset (\mathbb{Z}_p)^n
$$
primitive if one of the $x_i$ is invertible. Where does this terminology come from and why should I care about the special case of primitive zeros?

Comment: It is motivated by the case of integral points: an $n$-tuple of integers $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is called *primitive* if the coordinates have gcd 1. For example, $(6,10,15)$ is a primitive triple in $\mathbf Z^3$.  In the $p$-adic integers, where there is just one prime, saying an $n$-tuple has no common prime factor is the same as one of the coordinates not being divisible by $p$, which is the same as the mod $p$ reduction of the $n$-tuple not being $(0,0,\ldots,0)$, which is the same as some coordinate being invertible due to the "accident" that $\mathbf Z_p - p\mathbf Z_p = \mathbf Z_p^\times$.

Comment: The reason you should care about primitive solutions is because you may often be able to refine them to actual solutions by some version of Hensel's lemma. Just read further to see *how* he uses the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Let $K$ be a field. Then "the $K$-valued points of projective $n$-space", denoted $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$, is equal to the set of $(n+1)$-tuples $(x_0, x_1, \ldots,x_n)$, with at least one coordinate nonzero, modulo the equivalence relation of scaling: for nonzero $t$ in $K$, we identify $(x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ with$$t(x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (tx_0, tx_1, \ldots, tx_n).$$We write $[x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ for the equivalence class of $(x_0, \ldots, x_n)$ and refer to $(x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ as "homogeneous coordinates" for the projective point $[x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n]$. One particular thing to note is that the set $K^n$ embeds naturally in
$\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ via $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ goes to $[1, x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, and in a sense $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ is a kind of completion of $K^n$.

Just as one considers "closed algebraic" subsets of $K^n$ determined by roots of polynomials $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, one considers "closed algebraic" subsets of $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ determined by roots of *homogeneous* polynomials $F(x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$. The word "homogeneous" means that each summand of $F$ has the same total degree. If that degree is $d$, then$$F(tx_0, tx_1, \ldots, tx_n) = t^d F(x_0, x_1, ..., x_n),$$and therefore if$$[x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n] = [x'_0, x'_1, \ldots, x'_n]$$in $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ then$$F(x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n) = 0$$if and only if$$F(x_0', x_1',\ldots, x_n') = 0.$$So the question "is $F = 0$?" is well-defined on projective points. Moreover, given $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, one can "complete" it to a homogeneous polynomial $F(x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ by adding extra powers of $x_0$ as necessary (typical example: $1 + x_1 + x_1x_2$ becomes $x_0^2 + x_0 x_1 + x_1 x_2$). And under the embedding of $K^n$ into $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ that I described above, the algebraic set $f = 0$ in $K^n$ embeds into its closure $F = 0$ in $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$.

Algebraic geometry starts off with "affine" algebraic varieties, built out of equations $f$ in a fixed $K^n$, but eventually it generalizes to "global" algebraic varieties that are patched together out of such things, and the very first examples are projective varieties. One can patch $\mathbb{P}^n(K)$ out of $n+1$ copies of $K^n$, and the same goes for algebraic subsets.

Anyway, that is the context. Let me return to your question. Suppose
$R$ is a domain and $K$ is its fraction field. Given a projective point
$[x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, we can write$$x_i = {{y_i}\over{z_i}}$$ with $y_i$, $z_i$ in $R$ (and $z_i$ nonzero), and then multiplying the whole tuple by the scalar $z_0z_1\ldots z_n$ we can arrange that all the $x_i$ lie in $R$. But
can we do better? When $R$ is a UFD, then there is a well-defined greatest common divisor $d$ of the $x_i$, and we can multiply the whole tuple by the scalar $1/d$ to arrange that the $x_i$ have no common factor. This gives a "primitive"
representative of the equivalence class. When furthermore $R$ is a PID
(such as $\mathbb{Z}$ or a DVR like $\mathbb{Z}_p$), for primitive $[x_0, \ldots, x_n]$ one will even have$$Rx_0 + Rx_1 + \ldots + Rx_n = R$$as ideals.